# Setting a Php $_SERVER value ($_SERVER['something']) using Apache .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible using .htaccess or other apache powers to set a custom server value in the php array $_SERVER.

for example

```
if($_SERVER['is_special']) {
    echo "Yeah for us!";
} else {
    echo "No you fool!";
}
```

I realize I ask a lot of questions that the answer is no so feel free to say so.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try the [`SetEnv` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

```
SetEnv is_special foobar
```

Comment: There it is!

  'is_special' => string 'foobar' (length=6)

Comment: Note that you need mod_env to do this.

Comment: Try and avoid polluting the $_SERVER variable. I would recommend creating some sort of Registry class if you want to store global data.

Comment: Of course you can write on $_SERVER variable, it's recommended for server specified configuration (such as API key etc... Browser type detected, country detection etc...)

Comment: So it is not possible with just php code to randomly create a **$_SERVER** variable and assign a value for it.

Comment: Is it possible to set an environment variable to be a nested array with SetEnv?

Comment: If you're like me and the variable set with `SetEnv` is not showing up in `$_SERVER`, check if something like `suexec` is being used. If there is, you might be completely out-of-luck and no variables set with `SetEnv` will be passed down. A common workaround is to use a custom handler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724113/3649573