# Add entry to $_SERVER in extension

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I need to add an entry to the superglobal $_SERVER-array within a PHP extension. I am quite sure that `php_register_variable()` will do the job, paasing key and value as arguments; but I have no idea what to pass as 3rd argument. Unfortunately documentation on this topic is rather sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I normally use:

```
zval** arr;
if (zend_hash_find(&EG(symbol_table), "_SERVER", 8, (void**)&arr) != FAILURE) {
    add_assoc_string(*arr, "foo", "bar", 1);
}
```

See [Extension Writing Part II: Parameters, Arrays, and ZVALs](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1022#Heading5) for possible value types.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good; and thanks again for that link, what a shame I was not able to find that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it through Apache's SetEnv directive using mod_env module.

See [Setting a Php $_SERVER value ($_SERVER['something']) using Apache .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612228/setting-a-php-server-value-serversomething-using-apache-htaccess) for reference.

Comment: Er... He's writing a PHP extension in C language, not a PHP-powered web site.

Comment: That's true. My bad. I didn't read carefully enough. Anyway, AFAIK $_SERVER array contains environmental variables provided by the server software, so I think it's not possible to add them any other way.

Comment: $_SERVER contains env-vars, but is filled by PHP (e.g. in sapi/cli/php_cli.c). But it should be possible to add entries from within an extension and independent of any sapi.