# Setting a DYNAMIC Php $_SERVER value ($_SERVER['something']) using Apache .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is an exension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612228/setting-a-php-server-value-serversomething-using-apache-htaccess) where we learn that we can set a `$_SERVER` var using `SetEnv`.

The next question is: Is there a way to use SetEnv essentially like this:

/var/www/www.example.com/module/unique_section/.htaccess:

```
SetEnv RESOURCE_ROOT %{DIRECTORY}
```

/var/www/www.example.com/module/unique_section/some/path/file.php

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['RESOURCE_ROOT']; ?>
```

Output: `/var/www/www.example.com/module/unique_section/`

Comment: So you *specifically* want the directory the `.htaccess` file is in?

Comment: I'm asking two questions, really: (1) Is it possible to use variables when setting variables? (The answers below tell me, yes); and (2) How can I use that functionality to set an environment variable with the directory the .htaccess file is in?

Comment: OK. The question is, can a `RewriteRule` known what directory the `.htaccess` file is in. I don't think so... but you could use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` plus some static string... I'll research this further...

Comment: Why would you need to know this?

Comment: After some research I am fairly certain that there's no way a `.htaccess` file can know the path to itself. So I think you'll need to use hardcoded paths...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the information you require, you *may* be able to do this with a `RewriteRule`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=RESOURCE_ROOT:%1]
```

will set the PHP var `$_SERVER['RESOURCE_ROOT']` or `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_RESOURCE_ROOT']` to your Apache Document Root. See [the mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for full details, but some combination of `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`, `%{PATH_INFO}` and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` may work for you.

I don't think it's possible for the `.htaccess` file to know what directory it resides in. So I think you'll need to use hardcoded paths inside your `.htaccess` file. As an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=RESOURCE_ROOT:%1/module/unique_section/]
```

Answer (score 4):

as far as I can tell, setEnv doesn't have access to the apache environment variables. So the %{DIRECTORY} wouldn't work unless you wanted the value to be specifically "%{DIRECTORY}". Using mod_rewrite, this worked for me to get the path of the file being loaded:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ((.*)/)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=RESOURCE_ROOT:%1]
```

outputs:

```
var_dump(__FILE__);
//outputs: string(27) "/var/www/sub/test/index.php" 
var_dump($_SERVER['RESOURCE_ROOT']);
//outputs: string(24) "/var/www/sub/test/"
```

Other than that, is there anything wrong with just using php and doing `dirname(__FILE__)` or `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`?

Comment: THANKS! This is VERY close to what I'm asking, but I'm not asking for the directory that the script is in, I'm asking for the directory that the  .htaccess is in.  (Look at the paths and output in the question a little closer to see what I mean.)

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer AFAIK you can't find out which .htaccess file is being loaded without using php and just going up the path until you find an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `apache_getenv` to get what you want.

Link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php

Do not forget to read the documentation :

> This function **requires Apache 2** otherwise it's undefined.

Example :

```
<?php
$ret = apache_getenv("SERVER_ADDR");
echo $ret;
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
42.24.42.240
```

But, as suggested in this threat, you could just use `dirname(__FILE__)` and since PHP 5.3.0 you can use `__DIR__` as a magic constant.